# Angular 4+ send service from child to parent via interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I was searching for answer several hours..
Is possible in angular to send from child to parent service via interface?

- parent component
- child component (extends parent)
- interface for service
- service (e.g. locationService) (implementing iface above)

*Child extends from Parent*

```
constructor(public locationService: LocationService) {
 super(locationService);  //parent 
}
```

And parent looks like:

```
constructor(generalService?: IService) {
    this.myService = generalService;
  }
```

and than I want to do something like: `this.myService.doLogic();`

I got runtime error: **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ParentComponent: (?).**

Thanks for any hint or help..

Comment: Are you extending the component or the service?

Comment: Child component is extending parent component and location service is implementing IService interface

Comment: Are there any more child components that extend parent component?

Comment: Does your `LocationService` class implement `IService` interface? if not then, there will be mismatch in the parameters of child call `super(locationService)` and the parent constructor param, which is expecting interface `IService`

Comment: You have to change parent from `Component` to simple class. for more detail check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to design component inheritance in Angular framework is passing Injector instance to base component and injecting dependencies in the base component.

Base component class implementation:

```
export class BaseComponent {
    protected locationService: LocationService;
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        this.locationService = this.injector.get(LocationService);
    }
}
```

Child component:

```
import { Component, Inject, Injector } from "@angular/core"; // Import injector from @angular/core

@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    templateUrl: "child-component-template.html",
    styleUrls: [
        "./child-component-styles.scss"
    ]
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(
        @Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector
    ) {
        // Pass injector instance to base class implementation
        super(injector);
    }
}
```

Now in the child component you can use LocationService by calling `this.locationService.doSomethind()`;

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to extend `Component`, By extending component it brings only class property. So change parent from `Component` to simple class.

```
interface IService {
  doLogic();
}

@Injectable()
export class LocationService implements IService {
  doLogic() {
    console.log('service goes here...');
  }
}

export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(public locationService?: IService) {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(locationService: LocationService) {
    super(locationService);

    this.locationService!.doLogic();
   }
}
```